# On a multi modules project why the compile phase executed on the parent succeed?

Tags: maven

A Maven project has 2 sub modules, a and b:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Module A is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
</project>
```

Module B depends on A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>b</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The `install` phase was never executed. `mvn compile` on the root works. `mvn compile` on B failed. I wasn't expecting `mvn compile` on the root to work.

And even if all A's classes are excluded, the module B compile:

```
   [...]
   <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I do not understand and I do not find reference why `mvn compile` on the root works. I always thought that a module to be visible to other modules has to be installed.

I'm looking more for an explanation (with ideally link to a ref doc) on why and how maven is playing with the classpath/classloader when building modules than an explanation on the reactor sorting.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add log output's here..furthermore why don't you expect to run `mvn compile` from root working ?

Comment: Because I always thought that a module to be visible to other modules has to be installed using the 'install' phase. Log output is pretty verbose, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nithril/97a8cc747436b1a8555b764eb1167527)

Comment: @NicolasLabrot `I always thought that a module to be visible to other modules has to be installed using the 'install' phase` true for _isolated contexts_ such as building 1 module, false for _complete contexts_ such executing a build for a parent. I tried to explain this into more detail below.

Comment: Within a multi module build there is no need to do `mvn clean install` a `mvn clean package` or if you have integration tests a `mvn clean verify` will work no install needed...If you have errors using this your build is wrong...

Comment: @NicolasLabrot Of course is your output verbose cause it's debugging output using `-X` ...

Comment: @NicolasLabrot You have mentioned you have issues/understanding issue related to classpath ? What is the real problem you have? Can you elaborate a little bit more...

Comment: My real problem is understanding the rules (ie. the specification) and then the limitation

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Because of the *execution context* for which the [reactor](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) is to blame.

---

**Long version**:

Building a single module which requires a dependency, implies the dependency must exist or be downloaded in the local repo. Since it's one of your modules which can't be downloaded from a remote repo nor was it installed in the local repo, the build will fail.

However, when building a parent module, maven will look to see if there are modules that depend on other modules, and build them in an appropriate order, so they'll be *contextually available* when required. From the docs:

> **Reactor Sorting**
>
> Because modules within a multi-module build can depend
> on each other, it is important that The reactor sorts all the projects
> in a way that guarantees any project is built before it is required.
>
> The following relationships are honoured when sorting projects:
>
> - a project dependency on another module in the build
> - a plugin declaration where the plugin is another modules in the build
> - a plugin dependency on another module in the build
> - a build extension declaration on another module in the build
> - the order declared in the `<modules>` element (if no other rule applies)

---

It's difficult to find an analogy in real life, but perhaps this will do:

- the maven project: you're given a Lego set for a complex building
- compiling one module only: you're given only one page from the instructions to build a floor which is composed of previously built rooms => without knowing how to build the rooms or having them already built, you can't assemble the floor
- compiling the entire project: you're given the entire set of instructions => having the complete instruction will make it easy to first build the rooms, and then assemble them into floors

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's not really answer my question. I'm looking more for an explanation (with ideally link to a ref doc) on why and how maven is playing with the classpath/classloader when building modules than an explanation on the reactor sorting. It's maybe what you mean by `contextually available` but it's a bit vague

Comment: @NicolasLabrot Unfortunately finding references in the maven docs is difficult as it's not that comprehensive. The only 2 relevant that I know and remember of, are the reactor link that I already provided, and the one regarding [aggregation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation). I'll try to find some more when time allows

Comment: @Morfic One thing I don't understand is `Since it's one of your modules which can't be downloaded from a remote repo nor was it installed in the local repo, the build will fail.`...This means you go to a module and do `mvn clean package` or something which is simply wrong. That's why maven has things like `mvn -pl ...`?... Furthermore things related to plugin in another module I have my doubts where you do you get this from? The order is only defined by dependencies...and is unrelated to build extensions etc...?

Comment: @khmarbaise Apologies, English is not my primary language, so any feedback for improvements or clarifications is welcome. **1)** You're absolutely right about being able to use `mvn -pl` (maybe add `-am` as well), but my understanding is that OP is curious about why executing `mvn compile` on the parent works fine, while on a module that depends on another one fails, for a brand new project where nothing has been installed in the local repo. You can do it with `-pl` or go to the module, or from the IDE, but anyway it fails, right?

Comment: @khmarbaise I was merely trying to explain that maven behaves differently when running compile on the parent, in the sense that it figures out that some modules depend on others, and builds them in an appropriate order, so they're available when those that require them are build. **2)** Thanks for pointing out the `plugin` thingie, some words got lost when pasting from the [maven guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html). Please let me know if I missed something.